# When Would This INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE Fail?

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique-constraint

I was troubleshooting an `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement due to a constraint error, but I irreversibly edited the row in question, and I'm no longer getting the error. I'm pretty sure I edited either `request_path` or `target_path`. Some of the values that were already there for certain area:

```
store_id |   id_path    | is_system
   6     | category/494 |     1
```

The query was

```
INSERT INTO `core_url_rewrite` (`store_id`,`category_id`,`product_id`,`id_path`,`request_path`,`target_path`,`is_system`) 
VALUES (6, 494, NULL, 'category/494', 'lessons/teacher-s-planning-calendar/n-a', 'catalog/category/view/id/494', 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`),
    `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), 
    `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), 
    `id_path` = VALUES(`id_path`), 
    `request_path` = VALUES(`request_path`), 
    `target_path` = VALUES(`target_path`), 
    `is_system` = VALUES(`is_system`)
```

The error was

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'category/494-1-6' 
for key 'UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID'
```

There are two unique keys on this table.

```
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID` (`id_path`,`is_system`,`store_id`)
```

I'm no longer getting this constraint error after manually changing some values accidentally on the row. What would cause my query to prompt that constraint error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if fixing the first uniqueness constraint (by updating the conflicting row instead of inserting a new one) causes the second one to fail.

For example, let's say your table already has the following rows:

```
(6, 494, NULL, 'category/123', 'lessons/teacher-s-planning-calendar/n-a', 'catalog/category/view/id/123', 1),
(6, 494, NULL, 'category/494', 'lessons/foobar/whatever', 'catalog/category/view/id/494', 1);
```

Then trying to insert your new row:

```
(6, 494, NULL, 'category/494', 'lessons/teacher-s-planning-calendar/n-a', 'catalog/category/view/id/494', 1)
```

will cause the first constraint to fail (since a row with `request_path = 'lessons/teacher-s-planning-calendar/n-a'` and `store_id = 6` already exists in the table), and thus the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause will cause the conflicting row to be updated instead.  But this will cause it to violate the *second* constraint, since there's already *another* row in the table with `id_path = 'category/494'`, `is_system = 1` and `store_id = 6`.

[Here's a simple example on SQLize demonstrating this behavior.](http://www.sqlize.com/i4GV8G1q9D)

---

In fact, [what really happens](//dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is that, if an `INSERT` statement with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` violates multiple uniqueness constraints, MySQL will try to apply the update to *all* the conflicting rows.  For an update like this, setting all the columns to fixed values, that's pretty much *guaranteed* to result in a further constraint violation, since it's effectively trying to make two different rows in table identical.

As the linked documentation notes:

> In general, you should try to avoid using an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

Comment: I think this is *exactly* what happened. The other unique constraint failed, but the error was on the second one you listed! Doesn't seem like there's a simple and elegant solution for this particular issue, as I think there are some integrity issue before even getting to this point because I would need to do something about `request_path` in `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` as well as the new record I want to insert.

Answer (score 2):

**Q: What would cause my query to prompt that constraint error?**

The `INSERT` action encountered a duplicate key error on the first unique key `(request_path,store_id)`. That error was caught by MySQL, and MySQL then performed an operation equivalent to

```
UPDATE core_url_rewrite
   SET store_id     = ?
     , category_id  = ?
     , product_id   = ?
     , id_path      = ?
     , request_path = ?
     , target_path  = ?
     , is_system    = ?
 WHERE ( request_path = ? AND store_id = ? )
    OR ( id_path = ? AND id_system = ? AND store_id = ?)
 LIMIT 1
```

The update action attempted to set the **`id_path`** and **`id_system`** columns (on that row) to values **`'category/494'`** and **`'1'`**, respectively.

That "duplicate key" error was returned from the `UPDATE` action. The statement only catches the duplicate key error caused by the `INSERT` action.

---

This part of the error message:

```
'category/494-1-6'
```

is a representation of the values in the columns making up the unique key that already exists in the table.

In the error message, a dash character is used as a separator between the values of each column. In general, we can't distinguish a dash that's a separator and a dash that's part of a value; so we need to take care in parsing that.

In this case, there's two dash characters, and three columns in the index, so we can pick out which value was being assigned to each column.

---

If the `INSERT` had thrown the "duplicate key" error, we wouldn't have seen it. MySQL would have caught that, and invoked the `UPDATE` action. It was the `UPDATE` action that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just have solved your problem, but I'm leaving the tip here to other people who came here from google like me.

This error also is produced when **url_rewrite_id** reaches **max unsigned int size 4,294,967,295**

The fastest solution is just truncate this table and reindex again if you are not using custom rewrites.

```
$adapter->insertOnDuplicate($this->getMainTable(), $rewriteData);
```

Seem like INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE (used by Magento core indexer) bumps this index each time indexer is run.

Answer (score 0):

Note as A.Maksymiuk suggested that reaching max unsigned int size can also be a reason.

In our case we were manually inserting and deleting a lot of rows in our ERP integration so the MySql AUTO_INCREMENT field was increasing a lot faster that actual records.

The error reporting 'Duplicate Entry' has to do with this MySql bug:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80373

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66566

In our case we changed the type of the column url_rewrite_id to BIGINT